# The alignement of a string

Tags: assembly, x86, abi

In a x86 stack an array of chars (string) finish when there is "string\0 + 4 NULLs", but:

```
| e | l | l | o |esp
| 0 | 0 | 0 | h |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |esp+8
```

The array will be the interval [esp, esp+9] or [esp, esp+11]? I.e. the 4 NULLs must be aligned in position+{4,8,12, ...} or they must be immediately after the first NULL (where the first string finish)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that wrong. A string array is an array of pointers, each pointing to a string. The array of pointers is terminated by the NULL (the 4 byte pointer). Each string in the array may be anywhere in memory, and each has its own terminating zero byte. Make a diagram if you are still confused.

Comment: I understand, and please, correct me: you are saying the interval is [esp, esp, esp+9] = hello\0NullNullNullNull.

Comment: No. You haven't provided enough information. The string and the array are not necessarily together. The string is terminated by 1 zero byte. Then you have the array, whose first pointer points to the first string, and it ends with `NULL` pointer. Also your string is backwards ;)